# Checking if SSE is supported at runtime

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd, avx

I would like to check if SSE4 or AVX is supported at runtime, so that my program may take advantage of processor specific instructions without creating a binary for each processor.

If I could determine it at runtime, I could use an interface and switch between different instruction sets.

Comment: Including which compilers and platforms you will be using would be a good idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7495023/4231385 probably answers your question.

Comment: Since it seems to be pretty far down on that page, `__builtin_cpu_supports()` is probably the easiest option for GCC 4.8+: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html#X86-Built-in-Functions . MSVC is bound to have something similar. They probably just use CPUID: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID .

Comment: some other possible duplicates: [What's the proper way to use different versions of SSE intrinsics in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584983/whats-the-proper-way-to-use-different-versions-of-sse-intrinsics-in-gcc), [Have different optimizations (plain, SSE, AVX) in the same executable with C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408136/have-different-optimizations-plain-sse-avx-in-the-same-executable-with-c-c) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25911959/995714

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GCC has a way of doing this that starts by calling `__builtin_cpu_init` then calling `__builtin_cpu_is` and `__builtin_cpu_supports` to check features. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/X86-Built-in-Functions.html

On x86, when using the C++ frontend, GCC supports "function multiversioning", which allows you to write multiple versions of the function, specify the target it should be used on, and let GCC take care of making sure it is called. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Function-Multiversioning.html

Comment: Despite the fact that this question was marked a duplicate you still taught me something new and useful. This is a good example of why we should not be to hasty to mark questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

On MSVC, `extern int __isa_available` has information about the CPU support on a MSVC build.

It is used by the vectorizer in MSVC 2013 to pick what assembly to run.